# Sending a value to xcode

Tags: php, xcode

I am currently making the login screen for my application and have it calling a php file which checks the validity of the user name and password.  The PHP file currently echoes "success" or "failure."  I need it to send a value back to the Xcode application I can store in a string based upon its response.  Any Ideas?

Comment: What kind of Xcode application? How are you "calling" the PHP file? Are you using a UIWebView or something?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly how you call will make it difficult, but i suggest just using a | character and sending more information. Then, in your XCode application (Probably an iPhone app i imagine), just split your string into an array of strings based off the | character.

If you want to go the long road, i suggest transforming your request into a real SOAP client/server request. You will then be able to transfer much more complex data but i can't help you on how to setup that, i did one iphone app and i don't want to touch that **** anymore.

Good luck